# AWS CDK destroy fails and requires manual intervention

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I created an `AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage` with CDK, and it has a base path mapping configured. When I run `cdk destroy`, it fails because I have to manually delete the base path mapping first. Is it possible to configure CDK so that no manual intervention is needed?

**EDIT:** This is the error message in CloudFormation:

```
The following resource(s) failed to delete: [mystage].

Deleting stage $default failed. Please remove all base path mappings related to the stage in your domains: api-us-west-2.dev.mydomain.com (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Proxy: null)
```

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: Updated with the error message.

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example of your CDK code that results in this behavior. If I understood correctly, this should be easy.